# What is the best way to secure Map API key in Android

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

What is the best way to secure Map API key in Android

I'm using .properties file to protect the Key but after decompilation or reverse engineering we will able to find map key. so what is the best way to protect MAP API key in android.

I refer below link
https://medium.com/@vontonnie/secure-api-keys-in-android-projects-f8eb4839701d.

step 1 : Step 1: In  project’s root directly create apikeys.properties file  and add API key:
API_KEY = "abcd1234"

Step 2: Add the created .properties file on .gitignore file to prevent it from being tracked and shared on GitHub, the info contained in the file remains on your local set-up.
#put your .properties file here
filename.properties

Step 3: Inside build.gradle file ( i.e. inside the Android block under the defaultConfig) you can load the key-value properties from the .properties file and access them as follows:

android {

```
defaultConfig {

    // Load the values from .properties file
    File keystoreFile = project.getRootProject().file("filename.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    
    try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile)) {
        properties.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String apiKey = properties.getProperty("API_KEY", "");

    buildConfigField(
            type = "String",
            name = "API_KEY",
            value = "\"" + apiKey + "\""
    );
}
```

}

Step 5: Access the BuildConfig class constant on main source code.
BuildConfig.API_KEY accesses the API_KEY constant defined in the automatically generated BuildConfig file — it contains various constants that are defined in the build configuration for the project alongside our custom fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to securely use Google Map API key on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62454340/295004) but you didn't clarify which Map SDK you are using.